# How to prevent VBA variables from being shared across Word documents?

Tags: vba, scope, ms-word

I have a VBA template project that runs automatically when a Word document is opened. However, if I open multiple documents, they all share the variables values. How can declare these variables to be only associated with the active window or active document?

I tried declaring them in a Class Module, but that did not help. Switching between opened document I can see that these variables are shared.

Any input is appreciated...

This what I have in my Module:

```
Option Private Module
  Dim CurrentCommand As String

  Public Function SetCurrentCommand(command)
    CurrentCommand = command
  End Function

  Public Function GetCurrentCommand()
    GetCurrentCommand = CurrentCommand
  End Function
```

**More Info:** The code/Macro start at AutoExec like this:

```
Public Sub Main()      
  Set oAppClass.oApp = Word.Application
  If PollingRate <> "" Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(PollingRate), "CaptureUserViewState"
End Sub
```

And the CaptureUserViewState is a Sub that resides in a different Module and does all teh checks (comparing new values to last recorded ones) and here how this Sub does the check:

```
If WL_GetterAndSetter.GetLastPageVerticalPercentage <> pageVerticalPercentScrolled Then
  'Update the last value variable
   WL_GetterAndSetter.SetLastPageVerticalPercentage (pageVerticalPercentScrolled)
  'log change
End If
```

Comment: Please show us how you declared those variables in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You don't give us much information, but I assume you declared public variables at module level like this:

```
Public myString As String
Public myDouble As Double
```

From VBA documentation:

> Variables declared using the `Public` statement are **available to all procedures in all modules in all applications** unless `Option Private Module` is in effect; in which case, the variables are public only within the project in which they reside.

The answer is to use `Option Private Module`.

> When used in host applications that allow references across multiple projects, `Option Private Module` prevents a module’s contents from being referenced outside its project.
>
> [...] If used, the `Option Private` statement must appear at module level, before any procedures.

**EDIT** You have now clarified that you declare your variables using `Dim` at module level. In this case, `Option Private Module` is irrelevant.

> Variables declared with `Dim` at the module level are available to all procedures within the module.

i.e. regardless of whether you're using `Option Private Module` or not.

If you're finding that the values are retained between runs, then that must be because you are running a procedure from the same module from the same workbook. You may think you're doing something else, but in reality this is what you're doing.

**EDIT**

In your class module, instead of `Dim CurrentCommand As String` try `Private CurrentCommand As String`. Without more information it's hard to debug your program. I'm just taking random potshots here.

Comment: Using Option Private Module did not solve the problem. The variables in this module are still being shared across Word documents.

Comment: @Alaa: Are they declared in a class module or a regular module? How can you tell that they are being shared?

Comment: I tried both class and regular modules. Let me explain, I track the vertical scroll position and I record the last position. Let us say that document A and B are opened. When I scroll down document A, I display a MsgBox with the last and current vertical scroll position. For now let us say that the values are (last position: 0 -  current position: 7). Now I move to document B. The MsgBox will be displayed showing (last position: 7 - current position: 0) although I did not scroll in document B so it both last and current scroll position should b at 0.

Comment: What procedure are you running? Where is the procedure code located? (i.e. what workbook, A or B?) How do you start the procedure? Are you sure you aren't running the same procedure from the same module each time?

Comment: This project is for MS Word and not Excel. The procedure is called periodically via a timer. For example, every 5 seconds the code will check if there is a change in the vertical scroll position by comparing it to the last recorded one. The problem is that the last recorded one is visible to other Word documents. How can I make such as this variable is per instance?

Comment: I tried instantiating the Class Module (i named it LastState)from the on document open event (this way I made sure that every time a new document is opened,  anew instance of the object LastState is created). This produced the same undesirable results.

Comment: Still waiting for answers to my follow-up questions... (instead of "workbook" I meant "document") To which I would add: where is the "timer" located? Have you tried declaring using `Private` instead of `Dim`?

Comment: I thought I answered your questions, sorry. The timer starts in the AutoExec macro. I tried both Dim and Private but problem remains.

Comment: What is "the AutoExec macro"?? This feels like we're just walking in circles. I don't think it will be possible to debug your code without having a proper, detailed description of what procedures are located exactly where and what each of them contains. Sorry, I don't think I can help.

Comment: I have a macro named AutoExec this macro gets called automatically when you open a Word document. The time is located in it. Look at the code under "The code/Macro start at AutoExec like this" section in my initial post above. This is exactly how the timer is initialized and called.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is store multiple versions of the variables, one set per document.
So I would suggest that you create a simple class to hold the different values.
You then store them in a collection mapping the data-set with the document name or similar as the key.

In classmodule (MyData), marked as public:

```
Public data1 as String
Public data2 as Integer
```

In module with the event-handlers:

```
Dim c as new Collection 'module global declaration

Sub AddData()
  Dim d as new MyData 'Your data set
  d.data1 = "Some value"
  d.data2 = 42
  c.add Value:=d, Key:=ActiveDocument.name
End Sub
```

Then when you enter the event-handler you retrieve the data and use the specific set for the currently active document.

```
Sub EventHandler()
  Dim d as MyData
  set d = c.item(ActiveDocument.name)
  'use data
  'd.data1...
End Sub
```

Please not that this code is just on conceptual level. It is not working, You have to apply it to your problem but it should give you some idea on what you need to do. You will need to add alot of error handling, checking if the item is already in the collection and so on, but I hope you understand the concept to continue trying on your own.

The reason for this is because, as I understand the situation from your question, you only have one version of your script running, but multiple documents. Hence the script have to know about all the different documents.

On the other hand, If each document would have their own code/eventhandlers, hence having multiple versions of the script running, then you don't need the solution provided above. Instead you need to be careful what document instance you reference in your script. By always using "ThisDocument" instead of "ActiveDocument" you could achieve isolation if the code is placed in each open document.

However, as I understood it, you only have one version of the script running, separate from the open documents, hence the first solution applies.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to store the Document Specific details using
The Document.CustomDocumentProperties Property
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212718(v=office.11).aspx

This returns a 
DocumentProperties Collection
Which you can add new Properties to Using

```
Document.CustomDocumentProperties.Add(PropertyName, LinkToContent, Value, Type)
```

And then Read From using

```
Document.CustomDocumentProperties.Item(PropertyName)
```

A downside, or bonus, here is that the properties will remain stored in the document unless you delete them.

This may be a good thing or a bad thing